# what is ejb field type for oracle materialize view columns type rowid?

Tags: java, ejb-3.1

please help me.
In materialize view column type is ROWID (In the Oracle database).

Now I wont create Ejb entry class. Which type can I choose?

For example in my view
....

```
RECEIPT_DATE      DATE                        NOT NULL,
```

...
in my entry class

```
@Column(name = "RECEIPT_DATETIME", nullable = true)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date receiptDateTime;
```

but for

```
D_ROWID           ROWID,
```

I dont know :(

```
@Column(name = "D_ROWID", nullable = true)
private ?????? dRowId;
```

Comment: According to documentation it is a NUMBER, according to this it will map to an `int` http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14188/datamap.htm

Comment: ok thank you. in that case my code will be @Column(name = "D_ROWID", nullable = true)
private Integer dRowId;

Comment: You can `private int dRowId;` but if you know that there are more than 2147483647 records then use a long , but i highly doubt you will  return 2147483647 recods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation *the internal Datatype of Pseudocolumn rownum is NUMBER*

You can use *Integer* type following the guide below as mappings.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14188/datamap.htm

```
@Column(name = "D_ROWID", nullable = true)
private Integer dRowId;
```